# Python 3 Regex TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: python, python-re

I am trying to parse the output from an SSH session using Paramiko module. Paramiko `channel.recv()` returns the output is bytes. I then converted it to UTF-8 string using `bytes.decode("utf-8")`. No matter what encoding I use, Regex always raises `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object` exception.

```
import re

bytes = b"optical temp=10950"
bytes = bytes.decode("utf-8")

pattern = re.compile("(?<=temp=).*")
temp = re.search(bytes, pattern)
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 7, in <module>
    temp = re.search(bytes, pattern)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/re.py", line 201, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: You are using `compile` wrong. If you pre-compile a pattern, you use `search` as a method, like so: `pattern.search(bytes)`

Comment: Thanks! i was using the wrong syntax all along XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is *almost* functional.

`re.search` takes the pattern first, then the string to be searched:

```py
import re

bytes = b"optical temp=10950"
bytes = bytes.decode("utf-8")

pattern = re.compile("(?<=temp=).*")
temp = re.search(pattern, bytes)
#OR
temp = pattern.search(bytes)
```